# Bind select field rendered with mustache.js to MVC model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mustache

I render a select field depending on previous selections using mustache.js. The field is rendered OK, but when I serialize the form so I can post it, the field isn't there and the value doesn't get bound to the model.

This is the mustache template:

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="controlField">
    <script id="controlTemplate" type="text/template">
        <select class="form-control" id="ItemId" {{^.}} disabled{{/.}}>
        {{#.}}
            <option value="{{Id}}">{{Description}}</option>
        {{/.}}
        </select>
    </script>
</div>
```

This is the javascript that binds the model:

```
getSubkontaApiCall(query, function(result) {
        var template = $controlTemplate.html();
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, result);
        $controlField.html(html);
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error);
});
```

I'm using AJAX, so I handle the submit call manually.

```
$form.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $form = $("#mainForm"); // I added this because I cache the form when the page loads, so speed things up, but since new elements are added, I'm recaching it
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
    $form.validate().settings.ignore = []; // using jQuery controls that hide some inputs and that's why I need this
    if ($form.valid()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Test")',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                $mainDiv.html(result);
                resetForm();
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                // TODO: handle error
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the `Action` definition, the rest of the action is not that important.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Add( [Bind(Include = "ItemId, ..., ..., ...")] ItemModel model)
```

How do I update the form so that it is aware of the new controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, `serialize()` only serializes inputs with the `name` attribute, so adding that did the trick.